# I am not able to get media details of instagram users through instagram API

Tags: api, instagram, media, instagram-api

Instagram is not giving Access to details other than basic.

I was using this API-

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN&count={number}
```

But not able to fetch details of users since 20th Mar 2018.
Error Getting:-

> error_type: "OAuthException",
> code: 400,
> error_message: "Invalid scope field(s): public_content,basic"

Earlier it was working fine and I was getting details smoothly

You can review permissions here- https://www.instagram.com/developer/authorization/
Here I am getting(applications no longer accepted)

Please guide anyone or give alternate?

Comment: Unfortunately we can only fetch owned data now using Instagram api. the media fetch only works for the userId the token is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone said that "Instagram reset the tokens for all users as a security precaution" from [here](https://codecanyon.net/item/instagram-journal/11593035/comments?page=35), so you have to generate a new access token.

If you create token by yourself, explicit or implicit way, that token is always "basic" one, and I don't know why(I've tried so many times...)

If you seek websites that help you generate access token, mostly they generate "basic" permission as well.

Comment: Thanks @YM cho, it helped for now and I am able to access data through link you provided